# How to add NULL vs NOT NULL contraint based on data in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For my semester project we are creating our own database. I'm currently creating the database and tables. I'm using SQL in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I want to make columns `Beds, Baths, Sqft` only be NULL if `Lot/Land` is selected in the Type column (if any other option is selected, it needs to be NOT NULL).

```
CREATE TABLE Property(
PropertyID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
StreetAddress1 varchar(n) NOT NULL,
StreetAddress2 varchar(n) NULL,
City varchar(n) NOT NULL,
State varchar(2) NOT NULL,
Type varhar(#) NOT NULL CHECK (Type IN 'Single Family', 'Apartment', 'Condo', 'Townhome', 'Manufactured','Lot/Land'),
Beds varchar(2) NULL,
Baths decimal(3,1) NULL,
Sqft varchar(5) NULL,
Acreage decimal(10,2) NOT NULL)
```

The solution will need to be in an ALTER function since I'm creating the table now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I for one do not see why this is being downvoted.  The OP has explained the problem and seems to have made an attempt.  Not only that, but it is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 5):

You want a separate `check` constraint for this:

```
CREATE TABLE Property (
    PropertyID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    StreetAddress1 varchar(n) NOT NULL,
    StreetAddress2 varchar(n) NULL,
    City varchar(n) NOT NULL,
    State varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    Type varchar(32) NOT NULL CHECK (Type IN 'Single Family', 'Apartment', 'Condo', 'Townhome', 'Manufactured', 'Lot/Land'),
    Beds varchar(2) NULL,
    Baths decimal(3,1) NULL,
    Sqft varchar(5) NULL,
    Acreage decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
    constraint chk_property_lotland
        check ( (type = 'Lot/Land' and Beds is null and Baths is null and Sqft is null) or
                (type <> 'Lot/Land' and Beds is not null and Baths is not null and Sqft is not null) 
              )               
);
```